# OKTA token for API access

Tags: okta, okta-api

I need a token( or key) to use in API request as bearer token.
The idea is to set it once for user and access resources without login.
I tried to use access_token for it, but max expiration time is 1 day.
So, I need a token:
 - With expiration time >30 days
 - which can uniquely identifies user
 - Contains authentication data, like roles and groups
Any idea how it can be done with OKTA?

Answer (score 4):

If you're using OAuth in conjunction with Okta, you can use a refresh_token (which can have a much longer expiration - including unlimited) to fetch a new access_token.

So, you wouldn't need end user (resource owner) interaction. But, when the access_token expires, you would need to fetch a new one using the refresh_token.

Comment: Thanks for response. It one of the options I though about. The downside of this is that client should be aware of it: client should use new token. Like it can't be done silently on backend.
I'm looking for solution where client is not aware about expiration for like 30 days: client just use same token to access resources without login prompt.

Comment: Just to make sure we're on the same page, there would be a single login. From that point on, when the access token expires, the refresh token is used to get a new access token. The purpose of this approach is to ensure that you don't need any additional user interaction (such as login) for the life of the refresh token.